# dynamic mapping override preconfigured mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I made a preconfigured mapping :

```
properties: {
                    code : {type: 'text'},
                    type: {type: 'text'}
            }
```

I have checked and the mapping is indeed `{type: 'text'}` for both.
But after I index (actually, update with upsert) the doc, suddenly the mapping changes to:

```
"type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
```

for both fields.

What could have caused this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the document you tried to insert had the type's type as a keyword.If you need to index structured content such as email addresses, hostnames, status codes, or tags, it is likely that you should rather use a keyword field. If you need to index full-text content such as email bodies or product descriptions, it is likely that you should rather use a text field. Read about it here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html